# Problem with Django: No module named 'myapp'

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Good afternoon,
I'm new to Django and I'm trying to follow a tutorial. However, when running the server, the following error pops up:

```
File "C:\Users\Jorge\PycharmProjects\web\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
from myapp.views import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'
```

This is a screenshot about how my files are right now:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `myapp` folder should be inside in your `mysite` folder

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Move `myapp` to `C:\Users\Jorge\PycharmProjects\web\mysite\`
2. In `mysite\settings.py`, add an entry as `myapp.apps.MyappConfig` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list.

Now do `python manage.py runserver` from `C:\Users\Jorge\PycharmProjects\web\mysite\`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to 'mysite' --> 'settings.py'
2. *write as it is*, Under
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'myapp',

Answer (score 0):

Add your app name in setting.py unders INSTALLED_APPS